# Using output of a regex to feed a function

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to run a function taking as a parameter the matching criteria of a replace call, but I'm struggling with it.
In the scenario of:

```
x="foo OFFSET_5 bar";
regex=/OFFSET_(-?[0-9]*)\b/g;
function timesThree(n){  return n*3 }
```

If I do a simple `x.replace(regex, '$1')` the output is, as expected, `foo 5 bar`. 
However, I want to pass that 5 to `timesThree`, I'm unable to, getting always `NaN`instead of `15`.

I tried `x.replace(regex, timesThree($1))`, but to no avail.

Where is my code failing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `timesThree(parseInt(x.split("_")[1]))`

Comment: @mplungjan - OP *seems* to want to use this as part of a `replace`.

Comment: Hence I did not post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do it with a wrapper function around the call:

```
x.replace(regex, (m, c0) => timesThree(c0));
```

Live Example:

```js
const x = "foo OFFSET_5 bar";
const regex = /OFFSET_(-?[0-9]*)\b/g;
function timesThree(n){  return n*3 }
console.log(x.replace(regex, (m, c0) => timesThree(c0)));
```

or in ES5:

```
x.replace(regex, function(m, c0){ return timesThree(c0); });
```

Live Example:

```js
var x = "foo OFFSET_5 bar";
var regex = /OFFSET_(-?[0-9]*)\b/g;
function timesThree(n){  return n*3 }
console.log(x.replace(regex, function(m, c0){ return timesThree(c0); }));
```

That works because the function is called with the overall match as the first argument (`m`, which we don't use), and then each capture group's captured text as a subsequent argument (`c0` in this case). So we pass the first capture group's text into `timesThree`, which converts the string to number implicitly via `*`. The resulting number is implicitly converted back to string and inserted.

Comment: @ Anonymous User - Thanks for catching the `const` thing in the ES5!